# Firefox does not load virtual host website while chrome does

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, firefox

I have created  virtual host for an apache2 website on linux ubuntu:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName motornetwebservice.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Motornet/webservice/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/Motornet/webservice/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/motornetwserror.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/motornetwsaccess.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set this value in etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   webservicemotornet.dev
```

And restarted apache.

Website **loads correctly in chrome**, but **in firefox I get server not found error**. I checked all firefox docs and reinstalled it on my machine, but I've got no solutions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you checked apache's logs ?

Comment: Yes, no data in access log and in error log

Comment: have you tried `http://127.0.0.1/webservicemotornet.dev` ? so instead of `localhost` you put the IP

Comment: this question might help you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/682501/apache-2-4-10-virtualhost-index-page-not-shown

Comment: Sorry, I saw that in virtualhost I have morotnetwebservice while in hosts I have webservicemotornet. Now it works.

Comment: haha, funny life could be, strange that chrome worked though ?!!

Comment: you can post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

If your website is on HTTPS, from Firefox version 62 and above [Trusted Recursive Resolver](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Trusted_Recursive_Resolver) program by mozilla could cause /etc/hosts to be overlooked for DNS resolution.

1. In Firefox Address Bar type **about:config**
2. Search for **network.trr.mode** preference name
3. Set value to **5** i.e. *Off by choice*
4. Verify, whether or not /etc/hosts is used
5. If it works then please determine what could be the appropriate value (0, 1,
   2, 3, 4, 5) for your set up

Answer (score -1):

Sorry,  I saw that in virtualhost I have morotnetwebservice while in hosts I have webservicemotornet. Now it works!